# How to search a document and remove field from it in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I have a `device` collection.

```
{
   "_id" : "10-100-5675234",
   "_type" : "Device",
   "alias" : "new Alias name", 
   "claimCode" : "FG755DF8N", 
   "hardwareId" : "SERAIL02",
   "isClaimed" : "true",
   "model" : "VMB3010", 
   "userId" : "5514f428c7b93d48007ac6fd" 
 }
```

I want to search document by `_id` and then **update** it after removing a field `userId` from the result document. I am trying different ways but none of them is working. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide brief information about what you did so far and provide more description like sample document, field that you want to remove from that document etc??

Comment: It may help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455937/remove-id-from-mongodb-result-java

Comment: my collection is like this and i want to search collection  it through _id and then remove the  userid field from database.                                                                  {
    "_id" : "10-100-5675234",
    "_type" : "Device",
    "alias" : "new Alias name",
    "claimCode" : "FG755DF8N",
    "hardwareId" : "SERAIL02",
    "isClaimed" : "true",
    "model" : "VMB3010",
    "userId" : "5514f428c7b93d48007ac6fd"
}

Comment: @dev What this link provide is removal of a field from result of some get operation. I want something like update where we provide search and remove.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove a field using `$unset` with mongo-java driver in this way:

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = (DB) mongo.getDB("testDB");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "10-100-5675234");
    DBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.put("$unset", new BasicDBObject("userId",""));
    WriteResult result = collection.update(query, update);
    mongo.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the functionality in the java driver:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("10-100-5675234")));
Update update = new Update();
update.unset("userId"); //the fields you want to remove
update.set("putInYourFieldHere", "putInYourValueHere"); //the fields you want to add
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Device.class);
```

The above code assumes that your `"_id"` is your mongodb normal `"_id"` which means that the variable you are looking for must be encased in the `new ObjectId()`.

Answer (score 2):

Long time since this post was opened, but might be useful for someone in the future.

```
device.updateMany(eq("_id", "whatever"), unset("userId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way is to replace the old version with the new version of you document (no userid).

```
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.put("_type", "Device");
newDocument.put("alias", "new Alias name");
// ...  

BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "10-100-5675234");

collection.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Answer (score -3):

The MongoDB documentation provides a [clear answer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to this question: use the $unset update operator.

Comment: it is not in java